# Python App is getting "Killed" on Ubuntu (remote), but works on Mac (Locally)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssh, python-requests

When I am running the following code locally with the Mac Terminal everything works fine, I can play around with it in every way I like, but when I am running it through an SSH on Ubuntu its getting killed as soon as I'm trying to return `x = r.json()` as a whole. If I only return a part e.g. `x[123]['date']`, then it still gives me the correct output, but if I run the code below, its getting "Killed":

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_BTC&start=1420066800&end=9999999999&period=300')
x = r.json()
print(r)
print(x)     #<-- here it is going "Killed"
```

Does anybody know why? Is it an SSH problem? Or an Ubuntu problem? I am using ZOC Terminal 7.09.5 for remote server work

Comment: It could be an encoding issue, try `print(r.encode('utf8'))` and same for every  call to print.

Comment: Looks like the Terminal to me. You should try an other SSH client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I hadn't enough Memory. Just resized it from 512MB to 1GB and now it works, but still slow.

Thank to everybody who tried to help and gave me an answer.